# Redirecting to Default Page from Subfolder gives error "resource cannot be found" in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using VS2012.

A menu in Master Page , containing Home (Default.aspx) and other links.

My Question is after login , user is Redirected to a page in a folder.

```
Response.Redirect("~/RegisteredUserPage/MyForm.aspx");

i-e http://localhost:3739/ServicePortal/RegisteredUserPage/MyForm.aspx
```

it is to be mention here MyForm.aspx is also inherit Same MasterPage
The problem comes here when i click home page (default.aspx), which gives error message i-e

> **The resource cannot be found.**
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /ServicePortal/RegisteredUserPage/Default.aspx

and URL is looks like: ***/ServicePortal/RegisteredUserPage/Default.aspx***

which is orignlly in the root directory i-e in the form:

```
/ServicePorta/Default.aspx
```

please help me out from the said issue.

Comment: Please write what URL have You assigned in Your code to the link that should be redirecting You to the home page.

Comment: In Master page it is <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the master mater page, Link should be like this -

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HomeHyperLink" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"/>
```

`<a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>` means Default.aspx in the same folder.

Comment: Exactly. I wanted to write this, but You were faster :P.

Comment: Still not work. now url becomes http://localhost:3739/ServicePortal/RegisteredUserPage/~/Default.aspx

Comment: You need to use a server control (asp:hyperlink) if you want to use the tilde ~. You cannot do this: `<a href="~/Default.aspx">Home</a>`